# Use scala reflection to initiate class with internal objects

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a class such as this:

```
class NormalClass[T <: NormalClass[T]] {
  object One
  object Two
}
```

and I wish to be able to create a new instance of the above class in a typed trait. The following `def make` in MetaClass creates an instance of T but it lacks the internal objects associated with NormalClass.

```
trait MetaClass[T <: NormalClass[T]] {
  def make:T = this.getClass.getSuperclass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

I have two questions, what is the reason for the missing objects and what is the best way, using reflection, to initiate a new class with internal objects from its type

EDIT: More Detail

The problem I am facing is if I then create an instance using make e.g. `var f = make` and I try to access and object method e.g. f.One.getSomething  I get the error `value One is not a member of type parameter T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think your problem in particular is the reflection:

```
this.getClass.getSuperclass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
```

Here, `this` is your instance of `MetaClass`, and there's no particular reason to believe that the superclass of `this` is the class you want to instantiate. For example:

```
class Foo extends NormalClass[Foo]
object Foo extends MetaClass[Foo]
```

In this case, the superclass of the object `Foo` is not a `NormalClass` at all, it's `java.lang.Object`. As a result, it won't have members like `One` or `Two`, and you'll get a `ClassCastException` if you try to cast it to `T`.

If you want the `make` method to instantiate an object of type `T`, then you need to get the runtime class of `T`, and then use that to create the new instance. You can accomplish this by implicitly acquiring a `ClassTag`:

```
class NormalClass[T <: NormalClass[T]] {
  object One
  object Two
}
trait MetaClass[T <: NormalClass[T]] {
  def make(implicit classTag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): T =
    classTag.runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
}

// declare a class and an object for creating instances of that class
class Foo extends NormalClass[Foo]
object Foo extends MetaClass[Foo]

// create a new instance of Foo and access its fields
val foo = Foo.make
foo.One
foo.Two
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the issue is. This works for me:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class NormalClass[T <: NormalClass[T]] {
  object One
  object Two
}

trait MetaClass[T <: NormalClass[T]] {
  def make:T = this.getClass.getSuperclass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
} 

class X extends NormalClass[X]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class NormalClass
defined trait MetaClass
defined class X

scala> new X with MetaClass[X]
res0: X with MetaClass[X] = $anon$1@404fe94c

scala> res0.One
res1: res0.One.type = NormalClass$One$@53d9f80

scala> res0.Two
res2: res0.Two.type = NormalClass$Two$@4d0948bd
```

If that doesn't answer your question, please clarify the issue you're having.